# Firebase Auth on Xamarin Token

Tags: c#, firebase, authentication, xamarin

How to make Edit data only by token Email login? I want to make data protection only for the owner to modify it.

```
using Firebase.Database; using Firebase.Storage; using
FirebaseAdmin.Auth; using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2; using
Newtonsoft.Json; using System; using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using
System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XamarinFirebaseApp {
    public class StudentRepository
    {
       
        FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://xamarinfireabse-default-rteb.firebaseio.com/");
        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = new FirebaseStorage("xamarinfireabse.adrfspot.com");
        public async Task<bool> Save(StudentModel student)
        {
           var data=await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel)).PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Key))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public async Task<List<StudentModel>>GetAll()
        {
            return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel)).OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item
=> new StudentModel
            {
                Email = item.Object.Email,
                Name = item.Object.Name,
                Image = item.Object.Image,
                Id = item.Key
            }).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<List<StudentModel>>GetAllByName(string name)
        {





            return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel))
                .OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item => new StudentModel
            {
                Email = item.Object.Email,
                Name = item.Object.Name,
                Image = item.Object.Image,
                Id = item.Key

            }).Where(c=>c.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<StudentModel>GetById(string id)
        {
            return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel) + "/" + id).OnceSingleAsync<StudentModel>());
        }

        public async Task<bool> Update(StudentModel student)
        {            
            await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel) + "/" + student.Id)
                .PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool>Delete(string id)
        {
            await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel) + "/" + id).DeleteAsync();
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<string> Upload(Stream img, string fileName)
        {
            var image = await firebaseStorage.Child("Images").Child(fileName).PutAsync(img);
            return image;
            // return "";
        }


    } }
**
```

Comment: It sounds like your looking for [how to allow only the content-owner access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Comment: Hello my friend
Thank you for your help
but I couldn't
Edit the code
xamarin

even work with him
I hope you can see this code and help me fix it